# Find the value without using calculator (Trigo)

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin ^210+\cos ^240+\sin10\cos40$

How to find the value without using calculator and without the formula $\sin^2A-\sin^2B=\sin(A+B)\cdot \sin(A-B)$?

Comment: Does $sin(10)$ mean $sin(10°)$ ?

Comment: Yes . It's 10 degree

Comment: Would the formula help to find the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A,$

$\sin^210^\circ=\dfrac{1-\cos20^\circ}2$ 
and $\cos^240^\circ=\dfrac{1+\cos80^\circ}2$

Again using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),  $$\cos80^\circ-\cos20^\circ=2\sin50^\circ\sin(-30^\circ)=-\sin50^\circ$$

Finally using [Werner](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) Formula,  $$2\sin10^\circ\cos40^\circ=\sin50^\circ-\sin30^\circ$$

Comment: How do we get the final result ($\frac{3}{4}$) in this way ?

Comment: @Peter, $$=\dfrac{2-\sin50^\circ+\sin50^\circ-\sin30^\circ}2=\dfrac{2-\dfrac12}2=?$$

Comment: OK, clear now ...

Answer (score 0):

The formula can be found by using the addition-theorems

$$sin(A+B)sin(A-B)=(sin(A)cos(B)+sin(B)cos(A))(sin(A)cos(B)-sin(B)cos(A))$$

$$=sin^2Acos^2B-sin(A)sin(B)cos(A)cos(B)+sin(A)sin(B)cos(A)cos(B)-sin^2Bcos^2A$$

$$=sin^2Acos^2B-sin^2Bcos^2A=sin^2A(1-sin^2B)-sin^2B(1-sin^2A)$$

$$=sin^2A-sin^2Asin^2B-sin^2B+sin^2Asin^2B=sin^2A-sin^2B$$

Comment: I mean how to find the value without using this formula ?

Comment: OK, but I will keep the answer because the formula is very nice and my answer gives insight how to get it.